# Безопасность ajax в iframe приложении ВКонтакте

Tags: javascript, ajax, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте.

Создаю `iframe` приложение ВКонтакте.
На действия пользователя поступают `ajax` запросы к серверу.

Например, пользователь кликает по блоку, блок исчезает.
В это время происходит `ajax` запрос с параметрами `viewer_id`, `block_id`. То есть, кто кликнул и на какой блок.

Но ведь такой запрос можно подделать. Как защитить?

Comment: А от чего защищаем? Что НЕ должен сделать злоумышленник?

Comment: У каждого пользователя свои блоки. Только он может их удалять.
Например, я пользователь, мой id = 1.
Есть пользователь с id = 2.
У пользователя с id = 2 есть блок с id = 4.

Я кликаю на этот блок, на сервер идет: viewer_id = 1, block_id = 4.
Сервер понимает, что это не мой блок, не удаляет его.

Теперь я беру и через инструменты разработчика открываю код страницы. У ajax функции ставлю viewer_id = 2. Кликаю, блок удаляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для каждого пользователя создайте уникальный хэш, например,

sha1(id_пользоватея.время_запуска_приложения.номер_блока)

, а уже этот хэш присылайте в приложение. Тогда даже если мы попробуем удалить чужой блок, нам придется пересчитать хэш(то есть, сначала извлечь из него неизвестные данные), это займет уйму времени, явно больше, чем полезное для приложения.

На стороне сервера хранится ассоциативный массив хэшей.

---

поясню чуть подробнее:
Если каждый пользователь может удалять каждый блок, но должен это делать только от своего имени, то тогда для каждого пользователя мы храним полный массив для всех блоков.
Если блоки у каждого свои, достаточно хранить только их.

В данном случае время входа в приложение - это слабый аналог сеансового ключа(Можно хранить любое случайное значение). Если требуется большая безопасность, придется изучить подробную схему безопасного обмена 
сеансовыми ключами. Для описанного случая того, что я указал должно быть достаточно.

Comment: Спасибо.

Ваше сообщение напомнило мне о том, что существуют сессионные данные.
Я использую django, а там с сессиями работать очень просто.
Просто при запуске приложения добавлю текущего пользователя в сессию.
Тогда и описанный вами хэш не понадобится.

Возможно сессию можно как-то подделать, но я не знаю как и думаю, мало кто знает и будет этим заниматься.
Так что должно получиться вполне надежно.

Answer (score 0):

Защищайте на стороне сервера. То есть, при первом заходе пользователя регистрируйте его у себя и проверяйте как угодно. А подлинность данных при входе пусть обеспечит ВК.

Comment: Не совсем понял.
Пользователей у себя и так регистрирую.
Но как это помогает избежать проблемы?

Как все происходит по шагам:
пользователь заходит в приложение -> vk создает запрос http://my_site.ru/?api_url=http://api.vk.com/api.php&api_id=... -> на сервере берем viewer_id из GET -> регистрируем пользователя у себя (или берем из базы, если уже зарегистрирован) -> генерируем страницу -> выдаем ее

при генерации будет такой блок: 
$.post('/delete-block/', {'viewer_id': <viewer_id>},...

где <viewer_id> - вставляемая при генерации переменная.
Но ее можно изменить через инструменты разработчика